# RxJava3. Why FlowableSubscriber onNext has not been called?

Tags: java, rx-java

I need to get a Subscription object to have an opportunity of unsubscribing listeners. For this I want to give a FlowableSubscriber to function.

Code:

```
FlowableSubscriber fs = new FlowableSubscriber() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Subscription s) {
            System.out.println("Flowable onSubs");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object o) {
            System.out.println("Flowable onNext");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Flowable onErr");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("Flowable onComlet");
        }
    };
```

Logs are:

```
Running...
Flowable onSubs
```

If I use lambdas it works, but there is not onSubscribe callback.

How can I get a subscription and why these mathods haven't been called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Flowable` supports backpressure you have to actually control how many items you can consume by calling `request` method on your `Subscription` so that they can be emitted by `Flowable` :

```
FlowableSubscriber fs = new FlowableSubscriber() {

        private Subscription subscription;

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            System.out.println("Flowable onSubs");
            subscription=s;
            subscription.request(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object o) {
           System.out.println("Flowable onNext");
           //subscription.request(1); you can also request more items from onNext method - it is up to you
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Flowable onErr");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("Flowable onComlet");
        }
};
```

In the example `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is requested on subscription however it might not be the best idea. The thing is you should call `Subscription::request` from `onSubscribe` to request initial items and then call it from `onNext` and decide how many items you can actually process.